# Problem when trying a simple loop in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script

```
#!bin/sh
a=0
while["$a -lt 50"]
do
echo $a
a='expr $a+1'
done
```

I get infinite echos of `expr $a+1`. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: try `while [ "$a" -lt "50" ]` Also you appear to be using quotes instead of backticks.

Comment: in this `a='expr $a+1'` those single quotes should be backticks to start with and your `while` condition doesn't evaluate well either

Comment: @MelBurslan : Also, he is missing the spaces around the operator.

Comment: Just to throw it out there, I prefer using for loops in these types of situations. `for a in {0..50};do echo $a;done`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your script has syntax errors. You may check shell scripts for problematic constructs using [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) on-line.

This will tell you

```
Line 3:
while["$a -lt 50"]
^-- SC1009: The mentioned parser error was in this while loop.
     ^-- SC1035: You need a space after the [ and before the ].
     ^-- SC1069: You need a space before the [.
     ^-- SC1073: Couldn't parse this test expression.
                  ^-- SC1020: You need a space before the ].
                  ^-- SC1072: Missing space before ]. Fix any mentioned problems and try again.
```

Fixing space issues by changing

```
while["$a -lt 50"]
```

into

```
while [ "$a -lt 50" ]
```

will instead give you the following:

```
Line 3:
while [ "$a -lt 50" ]
           ^-- SC2157: Argument to implicit -n is always true due to literal strings.

Line 6:
a='expr $a+1'
  ^-- SC2016: Expressions don't expand in single quotes, use double quotes for that.
```

The first issue reported is about the string `"$a -lt 50"`. In fact, you don't want to have a string like that here, you want `"$a" -lt 50`. By the way, since a string is always "true", *this is why your loop is infinite* (if the syntax errors are fixed).

The second issue is due to the checker detecting the variable `$a` inside a singly quoted string, where it wouldn't be expanded to its value (*and this is why the string printed is `expr $a+1`*). The solution is not to change it to double quotes as that would just give you the same string but with the value expanded. You want to execute the `expr` command.

Do that by changing you single quotes to back-ticks.

Your script now looks like this:

```
#!bin/sh
a=0
while [ "$a" -lt 50 ]
do
echo $a
a=`expr $a+1`
done
```

... and ShellCheck is still not happy:

```
Line 6:
a=`expr $a+1`
  ^-- SC2006: Use $(..) instead of legacy `..`.
   ^-- SC2003: expr is antiquated. Consider rewriting this using $((..)), ${} or [[ ]].
```

New shell code should really use `$( ... )` rather than back-ticks. Also, it gives you a warning about your use of `expr`, which is outdated.

The line may be rewritten as

```
a="$(( a + 1 ))"
```

The final version (plus indentation and a fix to the `#!`-line):

```
#!/bin/sh

a=0
while [ "$a" -lt 50 ]; do
  echo $a
  a="$(( a + 1 ))"
done
```

`bash` or `ksh93` version using `(( ... ))` for arithmetic evaluation, and with further shortening of the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

a=0
while (( a < 50 )); do
  echo "$(( a++ ))"
done
```

Comment: Your last  example is actually `zsh` or `pdksh` syntax. In `ksh93` or `bash` (or recent versions of mksh), you need to quote the arithmetic expansions (which undergo split+glob as POSIX foolishly requires). Basically, that code would start behaving strangely the day it's run in a context where `$IFS` contains decimal digits.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas "Strangely", yes indeed. Thanks yet again.

Comment: From empirical tests, it looks like `shellsheck` only gives a warning about unquoted expansions if it can't determine that the expansion will not contain glob characters or space or tab or newline characters (regardless of what it knows `$IFS` to be!).

Answer (score 0):

**Corrected Original**

```
#!bin/sh
a=0
while [ "$a" -lt "50" ] # mind the spaces and double quote the variable
do
echo "$a"
a=`expr $a + 1` # replace single quotes with backticks, mind the space between $a and 1
done
```

**Improvements**

```
#!bin/bash  # Why not put bash here? sh may not always be linked to bash
a=0
while [ "$a" -lt "50" ] # mind the spaces and double quote the variable
do
echo "$a"
a=$(expr $a + 1) # replace legacy backticks with $()
# Or better you can even use double parenthesis which allows you do
# (( a++ )) , note the C style increment operator here
done
```

---

<sup>**Note** For checking the scripts, use [[shellcheck ]](http://www.shellcheck.net/).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Or there's always going with a for loop:

```
for ((a=0;a < 50; ++a))
do echo $a
done
```

Fast and direct; no need for backtick execution.

Comment: But not `sh` syntax, that's ksh93 syntax, also supported by `zsh` and `bash`.

Comment: If you want concise, use: `seq 0 50`, or even `printf '%s\n' {0..50}` pure bash.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!bin/sh
a=0
while [ $a -lt 50 ]
do
  echo $a
  a=$((a+1))
done
```

and all spaces here is needed.